# 16 millisecond quantization when sending/receivingtcp packets

Tags: tcp, latency

I have a C++ application running on windows xp 32 system sending and receiving short tcp/ip packets.

Measuring (accurately) the arrival time I see a quantization of the arrival time  to 16 millisecond time units. (Meaning all packets arriving are at (16 )xN milliseconds separated from each other)

To avoid packet aggregation I tried to disable the NAGLE algorithm by setting the IPPROTO_TCP option to TCP_NODELAY in the socket variables but it did not help

I suspect that the problem is related to the windows schedular which also have a 16 millisecond clock..
Any idea of a solution to this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a higher resolution timer such as [QueryPerformanceTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [__rdtsc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95.aspx) being aware of their [downfalls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417693%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Similarly note if you are using wait functions you may want to call [timeBeginPeriod()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624%28VS.85%29.aspx) for 1ms resolution or even implement a busy-way delay function wrapped around a higher resolution timer.